# What should I do when my antivirus is not letting me access my router's control panel (because off a cross-origin script)?

Tags: router, anti-virus, webpage

I recently brought a new [D-Link DIR-809](http://www.dlink.com/uk/en/support/product/dir-809-wireless-ac750-dual-band-router), and when I tried to access its control panel, the page was just unresponsive.

After a few time trying to discover what the problem was (I even tried restoring it to factory defaults), I decided to use “Inspect Element” (the shortcut to open it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> on Chrome) to see the page’s source code and the console.

This is what I saw when I opened the console:

[image: Console print]

I disabled the antivirus (`Kaspersky Total Security 17.0.0.611 (b)`), and the page loaded just fine.

It doesn’t seem right to me to disable the antivirus to configure the web page, but even if I disable all it’s modules but the main one I still get the errors. **How should I proceed**?

Comment: Looks like Kaspersky is trying to add javascript to your pages. The way it's doing it isn't going to work in modern browsers. Normally, this would just not have an effect (aside from the error in the console) rather than breaking the page. Maybe update to the latest version?

Comment: @Ouroborus yeah, it is. The line that displays the first console error is this: `document.write("<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="http://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/5A327289-D8FE-584F-A29C-4EC4A7A12E57/main.js" charset="UTF-8"></script><script>ddw(\"txtFirmwareVersion\");</SCRIPT>");` and the problem is that there are missing backslashes (`\\`) before the quotation marks.

Unfortunately, Kaspersky is already up to date. Any other advice?

Comment: Disable your security software attack on secure HTTP websites and your problem will be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be an option in Kaspersky to disable the JavaScript injection which is causing this error. Check Settings -> Additional -> Network.

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Reference:
https://forum.kaspersky.com/lofiversion/index.php/t351027.html

Comment: Thanks to your link I confirmed it is a bug. Guess I'll disable the script injection and wait for a fix. Thank you very much!

Comment: @schmaedeck - Do yourself a favor, disable the MITM attack your security software is using on you.  Disable "scan encrypted connections" it means Kaspersky can decrypt ALL SECURE websites on your behalf.  These self-signed broken certificates that Kaspersky uses have been attacked before and will continue to be attacked

Comment: @Ramhound I'll do that. Thank you for your advice!